# How to keep message strings separate in Django app

Tags: django

Is there any official way to keep message strings in separate file, like Android strings.xml?

In android, we can use a string in different place without duplication.

If there is no way, what's the best practices?

Answer (score 1):

I needed once something similar, but for localization purposes. I used strings like these `__ENTER_BUTTON_TEXT__` or `__SUCSESS_MSG__` in templates with {% trans %} tag. And I stored actual messages in `locale\en\LC_MESSAGES\django.po` and `locale\de\LC_MESSAGES\django.po` as translation.

I guess it can be used in a single language project too.

However, I'm not sure you really need that in Django. Almost all these strings are in templates file and there is plenty of ways to not use them more the once. E.g. templates extending, {% include %} tag, custom tags and so on.